# PageObject instance call does something

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, pageobjects

So I have a page object which handles all the major functionalities of the page the user is on. I want to do it so when the instance of the page object is called something happens.In the current situation I have:

`public MyPageObject MY_SCREEN = new MyPageObject(this);`

and when I call `MY_SCREEN.fillMyScreenFields();`
I want `MY_SCREEN` to navigate to that screen, without implementing a navigate function in `fillMyScreenFields()`

Comment: You have to navigate at some point. Either you do it within a constructor or in a separate goToPage() method.

Comment: @Andrejs yes you are right, but how do i call it inside the constructor,without creating a stackoverflow exception at compile time

Answer (score 1):

I'm still unsure what you're after and how you get a SO exception, but here are your options:

```
public class HomePage {

    Webdriver driver; // inject an instance using a DI framework

    // option 1: uses the above instance, created by DI or just plain 'new' keyword
    public HomePage(){
        driver.get("https://yourpage.com/");
    }

    // option 2: pass in the driver in your tests
    public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
        driver.get("https://yourpage.com/");
    }

    // option 3: best one, I'd advise against the above two options, 
    // there will come a situation when you want to init a page object, 
    // but you don't want to navigate to it
    public void openPage(){
        driver.get("https://yourpage.com/");
    }
}
```

Here's a [repo](https://github.com/andrejss88/Selenium-Page-Object-Framework) with a simple Page Object pattern example

Here's another [repo](https://github.com/andrejss88/AutomationFramework) with more complex Page Object pattern example that uses a fluent interface

(Disclaimer: both are mine)